# Is there any alternate way of web sockets in javascript client side from instead of php

Tags: javascript, websocket

Is there any alternate way of web sockets in javascript client side from instead of php.

I am using PHP to communicate but i am want same thing using javascript on client side. Here is my PHP

```
<?php

    $socket = socket_create(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);

    $message = 'hello';
    
    if (!$socket)
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        print_r("Couldn't create socket: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        die();
    }

    //Connect socket to remote server
    if (!socket_connect($socket,'10.201.1.114', '4000'))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        print_r("Could not connect: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n");
        die();
    }

    if (!socket_send($socket, $message, strlen($message), 0))
    {
        $errorcode = socket_last_error();
        $errormsg = socket_strerror($errorcode);

        echo "Could not send data: [$errorcode] $errormsg \n";
        die();
    }

    //echo "Reading response:\n\n";
    $res = '';
    while ($response = socket_read($socket, 4096))
    {
        $res .= $response;
    }

    socket_close($socket);
```

Comment: Have you taken a look at [WebSockets API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API) ? I'm not sure how the 'credit card machine' is setup to receive incoming traffic, but if you have control over it, you may be able to set it up to utilize WebSockets.

Comment: HI tied but some how its not working  here is my js that i tried

Comment: <script>
    function testing()
    {
        const fs = String.fromCharCode(0x1c);

        const socket = io('ws://10.201.1.114:4000');

        const msg = '00'+fs+'00120'+fs+'0020'+fs+'315spantik';

       // console.log(msg);
         socket.send(msg);

        // // Listen for messages
        // socket.onmessage = ({ data }) => {
        //     console.log('Message from server ', data);
        // };
    }
</script>

Comment: not sure where the io(...) is coming from, I'll create an answer with a example of creating a web socket, see if it helps at all.

Comment: @MuhammadIbrahim Web Sockets and TCP sockets really have nothing to do with each other.  Your PHP code above is completely unrelated to Web Sockets.  Are you asking how to make arbitrary TCP connections from client-side JavaScript?  If so, this isn't possible.  Please clarify your question.

Answer (score 0):

Agreed, let's not lie to each other, PHP is not the best for websockets for the time being.

Some alternatives I like are :

- nodejs : basically javascript server side, great ws support.
- python : with async support you get ws made easy.

These may help :

https://github.com/websockets/ws

https://websockets.readthedocs.io/en/stable/

https://sanicframework.org/en/guide/advanced/websockets.html

Then, if you really want your server made with PHP, you can always just build the websockets server with python or node.js and use messaging tools (like RabbitMQ, REDIS, ...) to relay messages to PHP asynchronously.

Comment: Actually i am using vue js on my front end . I want to communicate my credit card machine direclty from browser instead from PHP server.

Comment: Just want something from frontend not from backend

Comment: alright, got you, then why would you need something "instead of php" if that's frontend ? php is backend only...

Anyway, you should probably look for Vue store plugins, like this : http://iamnotmyself.com/2020/02/14/implementing-websocket-plugins-for-vuex/

Comment: PHP is working fine but sending request from frontend to php then to machine then response back to frontend is making job little difficult . Just want to communicate frontend  which is on vue js with direclty machine.

Comment: peer to peer is not really related to PHP or javascript.

Comment: then really I strongly encourage you to check about client and server. And associated languages. Seems like you are mixing things up.

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use the [WebSocket API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebSockets_API/Writing_WebSocket_client_applications). I will provide an example of what that sort of implementation would look like; this will be closer to boilerplate code than a fully functioning example.

```
function testing() {
  const msg = "some message";
  const socket = new WebSocket("ws://someaddress:port");

  // the socket errored...
  socket.onerror = (event) => {
     console.log("Socket errored: ", event.data);
  };

  // the socket opens...
  socket.onopen = (event) => {
    console.log("Socket opened: ", event.data);

    // since the socket is open, we can send messages now
    socket.send(msg);
  };

  // the socket gets a message
  socket.onmessage = (event) => {
    console.log("Socket messaged: ", event.data);
  };

  // the socket closes...
  socket.onclose = (event) => {
    console.log("Socket closed: ", event.data);
  };
}

testing();
```

Comment: Thanks i will try this solution and let you know :)

Comment: WebSocket connection to 'ws://10.201.1.114:4000/' failed: 
Socket errored:  undefined
Socket closed:  undefined

Comment: i am getting this error